# The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/xxx-MacBook-Pro.local.pid)

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed Mysql using Homebrew. Then when i enter `mysql_secure_installation`, and add the `my.cnf` file to `/etc/`. Also i have `unset TMPDIR`. But however when i enter `mysql.server restart` on the terminal, error shown below:

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL
.ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/kangshuais-MacBook-Pro.local.pid).
```

I have tried best to google and reinstalled mysql and also reinstalled the computer system. And speech the question on stack overflow, but nothing happened. I still got the error. Please let me know what i should do. Thanks a lot

Comment: The first thing to do is look at the MySQL log files.

Comment: @tadman it said `mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/kangshuais-MacBook-Pro.local.pid ended`

Comment: Did you find the `.err` file?

Comment: @tadman I found this file before. But after when i viewed some answers related to my problem, which said i should delete the file. So i did it.

Comment: The `.err` file, wherever it is, usually provides hints about what went wrong. The `server restart` command only gives a quick synopsis.

Comment: @tadman i view the error through `/var/log/mysql/error.log`